# SQL - 3 level hierarchy query with CONNECT BY?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hierarchy

Say you have a 3 level hierarchy as follows: Household (1-m) --> Person (1-m) --> Account

But there are only 2 Tables:

Person (3 columns are):

```
Person_id, person_name, household_key
```

and

Account (3 columns are):

```
Account_id, account_name, person_id
```

What are some ways to get a query that returns these results (ie ordered by household, person then account):

```
Household_key     Person_id     Account_id
1                     1             456              
1                     2             763
1                     2             801
1                     2             822
2                     3              54
2                     4              68
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the desired result that doesn't look like a hierarchy query to me - try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
P.Household_key,
P.Person_id,
A.Account_id
FROM
Person P
INNER JOIN Account A ON P.Person_id = A.Person_id
ORDER BY 
P.Household_key,
P.Person_id,
A.Account_id
```

IF I am mistaken THEN you will need to show some sample data in the tables `Person` and `Account` .